# I was instructed to make a program to determine the hurricane category based on the wind speed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hello my teacher assigned us a assignment where the program must calculate the category of hurricane based on wind speed. THE PROGRAM IS NO FINISHED it has 5 category's but I have only gotten this far because I CANT FIGURE OUT WHY when the program asks for the wind input I put 95 and then nothing happens. But if I type 67 it will print 0 which is good. but why wont it do It for the other? I want it to print 1 but I'm missing something. these are If then statements by the way. Also please don't comment on my post with useless comments... I'm just trying to understand my programming homework thanks you.

```
#hurricane weather 
#Category = int(input("Wind speed mph: "))

windspeed = int(input("Ask for wind speed: "))

if windspeed > 64 and windspeed < 76:
    print("0")
if windspeed > 65 and windspeed < 85:
    print("Hurricane category: ")
    else:
        if windspeed > 85 and windspeed < 111:
            print("1")
            if windspeed > 86 and windspeed <110:
                print("Hurricane category: ")
```

Comment: hint: look at your indenting of clauses.

Comment: okay to be honest I'm very new to this, I have NEVER seen code before and I have had only about 7 classes so far... so I honestly don't know what indenting of clauses means... also the code may look weird because the website made me type 4 spaces before each line of code but it doesn't look like the spaces showed above? not sure if that matters but yeah if you could maybe elaborate on what those are.

Comment: meatball means that your indentation for your `if` and your `else` don't line up.  You need to outdent your `else` statement and everything from there down.  Also, your comment to meatball will never get to him/her because you didn't use the "@" notification.  Please read the [tour] info

Comment: Thank you @jk622 I shall use that for now on, ill try the indentation to make them line up!

Comment: Also thank you @flyingmeatball for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hey bro looks like you are getting confused with how to write if statements. In your current code your condition which relates to the input of 95 is within the if statement for whether the users input is between 65 and 85. As 95 is not within this range it cannot continue past this point and so it wont run your else statement as it is within the if statement.

your code:

```
if windspeed > 65 and windspeed < 85:
    print("Hurricane category: ")
    else: # see here you put the else satement within the if statement
        if windspeed > 85 and windspeed < 111:
```

to fix your code it should be like this:

```
if windspeed > 65 and windspeed < 85:
     print("Hurricane category: ")
else:
     if windspeed > 85 and windspeed < 111:

 # if and else should be at the same indentation
```

But what you should really be using is  elif which means else if for example:

```
windspeed = int(input("Ask for wind speed: "))

if windspeed > 64 and windspeed < 76:
    print("0")
elif windspeed > 65 and windspeed < 85:
    print("Hurricane category: ")
elif  windspeed > 85 and windspeed < 111:
    print("1")
elif windspeed > 86 and windspeed <110:
    print("Hurricane category: ")
```